# Let $f\in Hol(\mathbb{C}\backslash\{a_1\ldots a_N\})$ where ${a_1\ldots a_N\,\infty}$ are the poles of $f$ show that $f$ is rational function

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Let $f\in Hol(\mathbb{C}\backslash\{a_1, \dots, a_N\})$ where ${a_1, \ldots ,a_N,\infty}$ are the poles of $f$. Show that $f$ is rational function.

I've tried to define $g(z):=\frac{f(z)}{\prod_{i=1}^{k=N}(z-a_k)}$ and show that $g$ has the form $\frac{1}{P(z)}$ where P(z) is polynomial

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $p_1, \dots, p_N$ be the *principal parts* of $f$ at $a_1, \dots, a_N$, i.e. they are given by the negative coefficient-parts of the Laurent series expansion of $f$ at $a_i, i = 1, \dots, N$. Note that the $p_i$ are rational functions. Then $g = f - p_1 - \dots - p_N$ is entire, i.e. holomorphic on all of $\mathbb{C}$. Hence we can expand it as a Taylor series
$$
g(z) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} a_k z^k
$$
Saying that $f$, and hence also $g$ has a pole (and not an essential singularity) at infinity means that
$$
g\left(\frac1{z}\right) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^0 a_{-k} z^k
$$
has a pole at $z = 0$, i.e. the series starts at some finite $-K$. But this means that the sum in the Taylor expansion for $g$ is finite, so $g$ is a rational function. Hence $f = g + p_1 + \dots p_N$ is a rational function.

Comment: @reuns I'm not sure if subtracting the principal part at $\infty$ is more elegant. You would be left with a meromorphic function which is bounded at infinity... As far I can see you'll then want to subtract the principal parts and invoke Liouville's theorem, but that's just the same argument backwards.

Comment: Sure you do as you wish, in Liouville there is one more step, we assume $F$ is entire and bounded at $\infty$ so that $G(s)=s(F(1/s)-F(0))$ is holomorphic thus analytic around $0$ and since $G(1/s)$ is also entire your argument applies